# expo install development dependencies

Tags: react-native, expo

Using Expo Go in bare workflow, per the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/using-expo-client/#prefer--expo-install--over-) it is recommended to prefer `expo install` of the [Expo CLI](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/) over `npm install` when installing dependencies. `expo install`, however, always installs in production dependencies.

Is there an equivalent to `npm install --save-dev`?

I don't seem to find one so the only solution I currently see is, after having installed using `expo install`, moving the dependency to `devDependencies` and running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `expo install --help` command :

> Additional options can be passed to the npm install or yarn add command by
> using --
> For example: expo install somepackage -- --verbose

So you can do `expo install {packageName} -- --save-dev` with npm or `expo install {packageName} -- --dev` with yarn

Answer (score -1):

`expo install` is a command which will use your default package manager only. So, if you use npm, then what expo install actually does is, it searches for the compatible version of a dependency with your project and then installs it with npm. so, you may as well use `npm install --save-dev`. I personally use npm for all my expo project, and there are no issues.

Comment: I understand that `expo install` is nothing more than a wrapper but it takes care of version compatibility. Using `npm i -D` directly won't benefit of that.